# How can I set an arbitrary (non default) attribute for an AD user or AD Contact?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, powershell

I have AD Users, or contacts that are *not* Exchange Mailbox users, or contacts.

I also have a SSO system (Ping Identity... technology similar to Microsoft ADFS), where it leverages the AD Schema attribute: `CustomAttribute1` to store information needed for SSO.  This `CustomAttribute1` was created by the Exchange Schema.

I would like to use `CustomAttribute1` for both AD Users and AD Contacts, as well as the Exchange equivalent user and contacts.

**Question**

Since the Exchange tools will only allow me to modify "Exchange" users, what is the way to modify the AD counterpart?  e.g. if the following command sets a mailbox...

```
set-mailbox -Identity christopher@company.com  -CustomAttribute1  chris@company.com  -WarningAction silentlyContinue
```

What command will allow me to update an AD user (non-mailbox) under the same schema attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active Directory users are modified with `Set-ADUser`.  A specific attribute could be modified with the `-replace` switch.

---

[For example, to update the Info attribute in Active Directory and replace it with a new value](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/12/22/powertip-set-custom-attributes-in-active-directory.aspx):

```
Set-ADUser john.smith –replace @{info="John Smith is a Temporary Contractor"}
```

---

In your case, you'd be using something very much like:

```
Set-ADUser christopher –replace @{CustomAttribute1="chris@company.com"}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Seems that the AD version of the attribute has a different name. ("extension" instead of "custom").  I'm using this command `get-adobject -filter {mail -eq "user@company.com"}  | set-adobject -replace @{ExtensionAttribute1="user@company.com" }`

Comment: @HopelessN00b: Please consider updating your answer to reflect the fact that `ExtensionAttribute1` is the `Set-ADUser` attribute name that corresponds to `Set-Mailbox`'s `CustomAttribute1`, as stated in @LamonteCristo's comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage users with `Set-ADUser`, and contacts (or users) with `Set-ADObject`.